# Honeycomb Conjecture proved by Hales

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, computational-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

I have some problems with the proof(you can see the paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9906042v2)) in **section 3:** **Honeycombs on a Torus**. As is stated in the article on page 8

> Before moving the cluster to a torus, we first move it to a cylinder. Pick a diameter
>   to the cluster (a segment between maximally separated points p1 and p2 on $\Gamma$). Then
>   move the cluster to the cylinder $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}v$, where v is the translation along the length of
>   the diameter . The map of the cluster to the cylinder is injective, except at the points p1
>   and p2, which become identified. Since p1 and p2 are maximally separated, the cluster
>   fits inside a square of edge length $|v|$ with a pair of sides parallel to $v$.

Here, I can't understand why $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}v$ is a cylinder. Besides, I don't understand how and why we move the cluster to the cylinder before we move it to the torus.

Hopefully, if someone have read this article, I really want to discuss with you.

Comment: Anyone who is also interested in this problem can contact me(wcs1165082064@gmail.com).